# angular-cli: How do I serve freshly-uploaded assets without restarting the server?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My app uses a form to upload images, which are then placed in `angular-cli`'s assets folder. They need to be viewable immediately, but as it stands they throw a 404; restarting the CLI solves this each time, but obviously isn't ideal.

I have `--watch` set to `true` as per usual. New source files are detected fine, but apparently new assets are not; if I run the server with `--verbose`, the new image is nowhere to be seen, but will appear on restart along with all the others.

Am I right in thinking that the `assets` folder is purely for files that aren't subject to change while the server is running? If so, is there somewhere else from where the development server can serve my images on-the-fly? This was certainly doable with `lite-server`, but I have lots of reasons to want to stick with `angular-cli`.

Comment: how are you hosting your production app? Are you using `ng serve` in production?

Comment: You are correct, the assets folder is only for static assets that are not expected to change unless you redeploy. For dynamic assets, you should host these somewhere on your server external to your app.

Comment: Thanks, folks – no, using Apache in production so this won't be a problem, but it'd be nice to have it run smoothly in the mean time. I'll try serving the images along with my API (already on a local Apache) which will give them a different host name (lots of URLs to edit! Don't I wish I gave them a changeable prefix...) but should sort it out.